# Normalizing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON response which is:

```
{"Neighborhoods":[    
{"Name":"Project A",
    "Balcony":false,
    "Sauna":false,
    "ProjectIds":["f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790","b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24"],
    "NextViewing":null,
    "Location":{"Lat":52.484295,"Lon":13.5058143},
    "SalesStatus":"ForSale",
    "TypeOfContract":7},
    {"Name"
```

I then use `pd.json_normalize(Response,'Neighborhoods')` for normalizing.
The Location part is then flattened out as I want, as two columns "Location.Lat" and "Location.Lon". My issue is "ProjectIds" which I get in one column as

```
['f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790', 'b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24']
```

But I would like to have it without '[] and the space in the middle. So that the output would be

```
f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790,b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to convert the list of strings into comma separated string, as follows:

```
df['ProjectIds'] = df['ProjectIds'].str.join(',')
```

### Demo

```
Response ={"Neighborhoods":[    
 {"Name":"Project A",
"Balcony":'false',
"Sauna":'false',
"ProjectIds":["f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790","b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24"],
"NextViewing":'null',
"Location":{"Lat":52.484295,"Lon":13.5058143},
"SalesStatus":"ForSale",
"TypeOfContract":7}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(Response,'Neighborhoods') 

df['ProjectIds'] = df['ProjectIds'].str.join(',')




print(df)

        Name Balcony  Sauna                                                                 ProjectIds NextViewing SalesStatus  TypeOfContract  Location.Lat  Location.Lon
0  Project A   false  false  f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790,b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24        null     ForSale               7     52.484295     13.505814
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ",".join() on the projectIds to convert them to string from list before you pass it to json_nornalize

Comment: Thanks Shubham! Can you please explain it in a bit more detail. How should I use join()?

Answer (score 1):

The way you can solve this is by using `','.join()` on the `ProjectIds` column:

```
data ={"Neighborhoods":[    
 {"Name":"Project A",
"Balcony":'false',
"Sauna":'false',
"ProjectIds":["f94d25e2-3709-42bc-a4a2-bf8e073e9790","b106b4f1-32b9-4fc2-b2b3-55a7e5348c24"],
"NextViewing":'null',
"Location":{"Lat":52.484295,"Lon":13.5058143},
"SalesStatus":"ForSale",
"TypeOfContract":7}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(data['Neighborhoods'])
df['ProjectIds'] = df['ProjectIds'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it.The last df you have alone on the last row, I assume this should be deleted?

Comment: @NewDev Please mark as solved if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Can I mark two posts as solved? Then I will do so.  Your post was very similar to an earlier response which also solved my problem.